# Php 5.6 command - yearly

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6

I'm using php 5.6 and noticed that yearlyOn() is not in the documentation. I'm wondering if yearly() fires every first day of January or the day it was set up?

Also, will yearlyOn() work for php 5.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 5.6, do you mean Laravel version or PHP version?

Assuming you're using Laravel 5.6, there's no `yearlyOn` option (it's only available on version 8.0 and above).

`yearly` runs the task on the first day of every year at midnight.

Comment: Hi, php 5.6 and laravel 5.4 and I think your last sentence is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you!